# Find the remainder when $2^{561}$ is divided by $561$ using simple congruence properties.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$2^{561}\equiv ? \pmod{561}$

Few observations :
$561 = 3\times 11\times 17$
So Fermat's little theorem is not useful here. Any hints ?

If possible, kindly avoid carmichael numbers/group theory/euler theorems as this is from elementary number theory and we have just started congruences chapter.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem is very useful here (and the Chinese remainder theorem).

Comment: Oh interesting, also 561 is a square free integer. but im bit unclear on how to put everything together

Comment: I have used Chinese remainder theorem for solving systems like : $$x \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \\ x\equiv 2 \pmod 7 \\\cdots$$ the exponent is throwing me off in present problem

Comment: Compute $2^{561}$ modulo $3,11$, and $17$, then put things together with the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Fermat said $2^{11}\equiv 2\pmod{11}$. That would means $2^{561}\equiv 2^{3\times 17}\pmod{11}$.

Comment: I see, ty :) and I have $2^{561}\equiv 1\pmod 3 $  and  $2^{561}\equiv  2^{4*140+1}\equiv  2 \pmod {17}$

Comment: do I get : $$x \equiv 1 \pmod 3  \\
x \equiv 2 \pmod {11}  \\
x \equiv 2 \pmod {17}  \\

(1)(11*17)(1) + (2)(3*17)(8) + 2(3*11)(8)
$$ ?

Comment: @DanielFischer please help, this is not giving me the correct answer

Comment: Why do you think $2^{561} \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$?

Comment: because 2 leaves a remainder 1 when divided by 3

Comment: Oh no my bad sorry, the remainder is -1

Comment: thanks a lot! let me fix it up quick and see :)

Comment: $$x \equiv 2 \pmod 3  \\ x \equiv 2 \pmod {11}  \\ x \equiv 2 \pmod {17}  \\  (2)(11*17)(1) + (2)(3*17)(8) + 2(3*11)(16)
 $$  this look okay or still see any errors ?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand

Answer (score 2):

We have $2^2=4\equiv1\pmod3,$

$2^5=32\equiv-1\pmod{11}\implies2^{10}\equiv(-1)^2\equiv1\pmod{11}$

$2^4=16\equiv-1\pmod{17}\implies2^8\equiv{-1}^2\equiv1\pmod{17}$

$\displaystyle\implies2^{\text{lcm}(2,10,8)}\equiv1\pmod{3\cdot11\cdot17}$

i.e., $\displaystyle2^{40}\equiv1\pmod{561}$

$\displaystyle\implies2^{561}=2(2^{40})^{14}\equiv2(1)^{14}\pmod{561}$

**Reference** : [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)

Comment: @rsadhvika, How about this?

Answer (score 2):

Fermats or Euler is exactly what you need :) (or anything else you know )

**what   you need to know is this :-**

> if $n= p_1p_2...p_i $  such that  $p_1,p_2,..., p_i$  are distinct
>   primes which means $GCD(p_j,p_k)=1$ for $j,k \leq i$ , and $x=m \bmod p_1=m
>  \bmod p_2 = ...=m \bmod p_i$ then $x=m \bmod (p_1p_2...p_i)
>  \rightarrow x=m \bmod n$

now GCD(3,7 )=1 ,GCD(3,11)=1 , GCD(7,11)=1 :-

$2^{{\color{DarkBlue} {16}}}={\color{Green} 1} \bmod {\color{Red} {17} }\\
2^{{\color{DarkBlue} 2}}={\color{Green} 1} \bmod {\color{Red} 3}\\
2^{{\color{DarkBlue} {10}}}={\color{Green} 1} \bmod {\color{Red} {11} }\\
2^{{\color{DarkBlue} {16\times35}}}=2^{{\color{Magenta} {560} }}={\color{Green} 1} \bmod {\color{Red} {17} }\\
2^{{\color{DarkBlue} {2\times280}}}=2^{{\color{Magenta} {560 }  }}= {\color{Green} 1} \bmod {\color{Red} 3}\\
2^{{\color{DarkBlue} {10\times56 } }}=2^{{\color{Magenta} {560}  }}=  {\color{Green} 1} \bmod {\color{Red} {11} }$

$2^{\color{Magenta}{560}  }= {\color{Red} 1}  \bmod {\color{Blue} {3\times 11\times 17}}\\
2^{\color{Magenta}{560}  }= {\color{Red} 1}  \bmod {\color{Blue} {561}}\\$

thus :-

$2^{\color{Magenta}{561}  }= {\color{Red} 2}  \bmod {\color{Blue} {561}} $

let me know if you dint get it yet :D