# If $x \equiv a \pmod {p_1}$ and $x\equiv a \pmod{p_2}$, then is it true that $x\equiv a \pmod{p_1p_2} ?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$p_1, p_2$ are distinct prime numbers

I have just observed this pattern when solving [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935059/find-the-remainder-when-2561-is-divided-by-561-using-simple-congruence-pr) problem. Is there a simple way to prove/disprove it ?

Comment: You need them to be distinct primes...

Comment: yes otherwise x=a mod p^2 would not make sense, I'll edit the question :)

Comment: I wouldn't say it does "not make sense," I would say it's false. Consider $x = 13$, $a = 1$, and $p_1 = p_2 = 3$, then $13 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ but $13 \equiv 4 \mod 3^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More generally, if $x\equiv a\pmod m$ and $x\equiv a\pmod n$ then $x\equiv a\pmod{\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)}$.

This is true because $x-a$ is a multiple of $m$ and a multiple of $n$, so must be a multiple of the least common multiple of $m,n$.

If $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then $\mathrm{lcm}(m.n)=mn$.

And if $p_1,p_2$ are distinct primes, then $\gcd(p_1,p_2)=1$.

Comment: wow! that's perfect explanation, goes straight into my head thank you so much (:

Comment: If you are answering a question for a class, some of these assertions require proof. For example, the fact that any common multiple is a multiple of the least common multiple actually requires proof. (It's not hard.) Similarly, the assertion about the case $\gcd(m,n)=1$ requires proof. Even the fact that two distinct primes are relatively prime technically requires proof.